# Is there a way I can share a bluetooth mouse between two OSs on the same computer?

Tags: windows-8, linux-mint, bluetooth

I'm dual booting between Linux Mint 16 and Windows 8 on my laptop, and I use a bluetooth mouse. Is there any way I can hack together a solution so that my mouse will work on both OSs without having to pair the mouse again each time I reboot into a new OS?

Comment: buy 2 identical mouses and wish for the best? you could also use a KVM switch.